# Sending pandas dataframes to PostgreSQL decelerates after approximately 150 tables regardless of how many records are being input

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

**Background**: A *python* tool that stores and manages daily stock prices. The data is stored in a *locally hosted* *postgres* database. There is one "master table" with a list of all stock's and each stock has it's own table for pricing data (currently numbering ~*500*), and these are foreign keyed to the "master table".

There is a python function that pulls a list of stock names / symbols and stores them in the master table (not shown here as not really relevant). A second function, retrieves the list of stock names from this table and then iteratively calls for pricing data using *pandas* webreader and stores them in the database.

The underlying ORM is *SQLalchemy* and *Psycopg2* is used as the database adapter.

**Problem**: The database performance seems to degrade over the course of the function running. It starts off strong and retains this performance for roughly the first 150 inserts. After that however, it slows to a crawl and drops to about 1 insert / second, maybe slightly less. I've attached a screenshot of the pgadmin dashboard, you can clearly see it just drops after a time.

This reduction in performance does not seem to be affected by the number of records e.g. If I just pull 1 day's price data for each stock, the performance seems to be identical to pulling 50 days worth of data. If I stop the script, and restart it, the performance starts off strong again, but degrades as before after a time.

[image: Database Performance Drop]

**Attempts**:I've tried a number of methods to solve this. I have tried using both the pandas to_sql function as well as [Pangres](https://github.com/ThibTrip/pangres/releases). I've also tried outputting the dataframe to a CSV and then using psycopg2's copy_from function to insert the records into each table. I've updated by code below to no longer use *iter* functions and use list comprehension per the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas/55557758#55557758), but it seems to me like the primary cause is still the inserting of records over a number of tables.

**Questions**: As I am not quite sure what may be causing this behaviour, I've put in a few potential thoughts below as to what may be the underlying issue.

1. Using separate tables is not a useful or scalable solution and all price data should ideally be in one table.
2. Potentially I am not making the best use of the sqlalchemy core API and relying too heavily on the ORM aspects / not properly implementing sessions?
3. Is there a better / more efficient way to get records inserted than Pangres / pd.to_sql? Note that copying a CSV didn't perform any better.

```
# Database basics.
engine = sqla.create_engine(f'postgresql+psycopg2://{dbuser}:{dbpass}@{dbhost}/{dbname}')
conn = engine.connect()
Session = sessionmaker(engine, expire_on_commit=True)
session = Session()

# The main function.
def insertData():
    df = pd.read_sql_table('stock', schema=schema_name, con=conn) # Read the names of all stocks in the master table.
    for stock_name, stock_id in zip(df['Stock_symbol'], df['Stock_id']): # Use list comprehension as faster than iterrtuples. Get the stock id and stock symbol for each row in the data frame.
        read_price_data = pd.read_sql_query(sql=f"SELECT * FROM stockschema.\"{stock_name}\" ORDER BY \"Date\" DESC LIMIT 1", con=conn, parse_dates={'Date'}) # Read the most recent price data (if any) for each stock symbol and obtain the date.
        with session.begin(subtransactions=True): # Opern a session. Removing this doesn't appear to impact performance in anyways, looking at the echo output from psycopg2, it seems like pangres commits every transaction anyways.
            start, end = dt.datetime(2020, 12, 12), prev_weekday(dt.date.today()) # Set start and end dates to fetch data. Setting this to even 1 day of records is just as slow as 20.
            price_data = web.DataReader(stock_name, 'yahoo', start, end) # Fetch the data frame from Yahoo.
            price_data['Volume'] = price_data['Volume'].astype(int) # Some of the volume data has decimal (e.g 123.0). Removing these to match-up with DB column type.
            count = len(price_data.index) # Some data manipulation to just ensure that the Foreign key - Stock id is captured in each df before being written to the db.
            sid = [stock_id] * count # As above
            price_data.insert(0, 'Stock_id', sid) # Inserting the above new column into the df.
            pangres.upsert(engine=engine, df=price_data, table_name=stock_name, if_row_exists='ignore', schema=schema_name, create_schema=False, add_new_columns=False, adapt_dtype_of_empty_db_columns=False) # Upserting the dataframe into the relevant stcck's table. Utilising df_to_sql, and psycopg2's copy_from also do not provide any benefits performance wise.
```

Comment: By chance is your code doing all of these inserts inside one big transaction that might bog things down as the administrative overhead of that transaction increases?

Comment: @GordThompson, so, it seems like it's one transaction per insert. I switched on the echo for sqlalchemy and got the following:

`INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT * FROM stockschema."aapl" ORDER BY "Date" DESC LIMIT 1`

`INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine select relname from pg_class c join pg_namespace n on n.oid=c.relnamespace where n.nspname=%(schema)s and relname=%(name)s`

`INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {'schema': 'stockschema', 'name': 'aapl'}`

The insert statement - not copied for brevity.

`INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine COMMIT`

Comment: Okay, good to know. As to point #2, it looks like you aren't really doing any ORM stuff so you can skip using session and just do `with engine.begin() as conn:` to keep the SQLAlchemy overhead down.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the info @GordThompson, was not part of my original code, but thought i'd try it out to see if actually made a performance impact. Unfortunately no improvement either way.

Comment: What makes you think the database is the limitation at all?  Maybe Yahoo detects you are scraping them and throttles you.  Loop over all the stocks, saving each one to its CSV file.  Then loop over each CSV file, loading them to the database.  This should clarify where the bottleneck is.